# Can't use draw9patch on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: android

Iam trying to run draw9patch tool from android sdk(ver.10), and it gives me exception with error trace like this:

```
sh ./draw9patch 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:437)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
    at com.android.draw9patch.ui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:44)
    at com.android.draw9patch.Application$1.run(Application.java:48)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. 
I removed OpenJDK, and installed oracle jdk, and now everything works fine.

Comment: I installed : java version "1.6.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_06-b02) to solve the problem. Thank you Serg.

Comment: I solved this problem according to your answer. Thanks! But after several days, I found that Ant is removed. When I try to install Ant, it complaints it depends on OpenJdk. Finally I installed Ant, but openJdk is installed along with it. Now I still can't use draw9patch... Do someone have a solution to make ant and draw9patch both happy in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm, interesting.. Iam now under Ubuntu 11.04 and I have Oracle's jre and ant working fine together..

Answer (score 0):

This means that either your computer is running no X or similar or that it can not connect to the X server (e.g. because you are logged in from a remote via ssh without X forwarding).

If you are running X, it may mean that some library path is messed up and the java executable is not able to find some libX* libraries.

Comment: hmm. Iam running ubuntu under usual gnome environment, and X is ok. Other java apps are working correct, so i guess problem with awt. Is that right?